# Using CSS plus selector with custom components

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, shadow-dom

In CSS, you can use the plus selector to select an element that follows another element. For instance, select all `div`s that follow `h1`s:

```
h1 + div {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

How can you do the same thing from inside a shadow DOM (or in Angular's case, the virtual shadow DOM)? That is, how do you conditionally style a custom component by what it follows after in the parent?

I tried using `:host-context()` like so, but it did not work:

```
:host-context(h1 +) {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

I know I can define this style outside the shadow using regular CSS, but I'd like to keep encapsulation and define that inside the shadow itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ::ng-deep to select shadow DOM elements. This will disable encapsulation for this rule *only* but allows your component's view encapsulation to stay enabled unless you change it.

```
::ng-deep h1 + div { 
  /* styles */
}
```